# Change text color with respect to background color with the help of CSS3 blend mode

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tries to set color of a link such that it automatically adjusts its color as compared to its background-color. I search for this problem and found that this can be done with the help of blend-mode or background-blend-mode. I tries but didn't able to make the same behavior. Here is my HTML and CSS code.

```css
.full-section {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.bg-black {
  background-color: #000;
}

.bg-white {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.bg-gray {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.top-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  zindex: 5;
  overflow: hideen;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.all-center {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.align-end {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.logo {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.button {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 180px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  background-blend-mode: difference;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row top-nav flex all-center">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9 flex align-end">
    <a href="#" class="button">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row full-section bg-black">
</div>
<div class="row full-section bg-white">
</div>
<div class="row full-section bg-gray">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: mix-blend-mode need to be on the container, the fixed element

Comment: for a black&white effect, `filter:invert(100%)`works fine too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.full-section {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.bg-black {
  background-color: #000;
}

.bg-white {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.bg-gray {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.top-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  zindex: 5;
  overflow: hideen;
  background-color: transparent;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;

}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.all-center {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.align-end {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.logo {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.button {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 180px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row top-nav flex all-center">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9 flex align-end">
    <a href="#" class="button">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row full-section bg-black">
</div>
<div class="row full-section bg-white">
</div>
<div class="row full-section bg-gray">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also take a look at [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) , it allows transition too :

Mind about how these two work through different browsers :

- https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters
- https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_mix-blend-mode

---

filter() possible example:

```css
.full-section {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.bg-black {
  background-color: #000;
}

.bg-white {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.bg-gray {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.top-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 5;
  overflow: hideen;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.all-center {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.align-end {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.logo {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.button {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 180px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition:0.5s;
}

.button:hover {
  filter:invert(100%);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row top-nav flex all-center">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9 flex align-end">
    <a href="#" class="button">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row full-section bg-black">
</div>
<div class="row full-section bg-white">
</div>
<div class="row full-section bg-gray">
</div>
</div>
```